# error using CrystalDecisions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

En mi proyecto tengo

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
```

Pero me marca este error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'CrystalDecisions' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Pero si tengo `Crystal Report` instalado, e incluso añadí la referencia:

> PM> Install-Package CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error?

**EDIT:** También he visto que para solucionar el error se debe de poner el proyecto con Target Framework `.NET Framework 4.0` en vez de `.NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile` y eso no ha solucionado mi problema.

Comment: le has dado un re-build al proyecto?

Comment: No lo había hecho ... Lo acabo de hacer y continua el error

Comment: Que versión de VS usas?

Answer (score 0):

Define el proyecto como plataforma de 32/64 bits, si se queda en `any` te seguirá causando problemas

Comment: No me permite cambiarlo, me aparece N/A